Sql Query Equivalency
I have a query written for the EBS Oracle Database. I have to convert it into a SPARK SQL query as I need to run the same query in my data warehousing tool. The Spark environment does not allow subqueries to use tables outside of their scope. I am not able to resolve the "exists" clauses here, can someone help?
SELECT
    b.line_id,
    SUM(a.extended_amount) core_charge
FROM
    apps.ra_customer_trx_lines_all   a,
    apps.oe_order_lines_all          b,
    apps.oe_order_headers_all        c,
    apps.ra_customer_trx_all         d
WHERE
    1 = 1
    AND
    CASE
            WHEN ( b.line_category_code = 'ORDER'
                   AND a.interface_line_attribute3 IS NOT NULL )
                 OR ( b.line_category_code = 'RETURN' ) THEN
                'Y'
            ELSE
                'N'
        END
    = 'Y'
    AND a.interface_line_context = 'ORDER ENTRY'
    AND b.line_category_code IN (
        'ORDER',
        'RETURN'
    )
    AND a.interface_line_attribute6 = b.line_id
    AND b.header_id = c.header_id
    AND a.customer_trx_id = d.customer_trx_id
    AND 
    (
    (SELECT osource.NAME FROM apps.oe_order_sources osource WHERE c.order_source_id = osource.order_source_id) = 'CONVERSION'
    OR
    EXISTS (
        SELECT
            1
        FROM
            apps.oe_line_sets e
        WHERE
            e.line_id = a.interface_line_attribute6
            AND set_id IN (
                SELECT
                    set_id
                FROM
                    apps.oe_sets
                WHERE
                    set_type = 'FULFILLMENT_SET'
                    AND header_id = c.header_id
            )
    )
    )
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT
            1             
        FROM
            apps.mtl_related_items
        WHERE
            relationship_type_id IN (
                SELECT
                    lookup_code
                FROM
                    apps.fnd_lookup_values
                WHERE
                    lookup_type = 'MTL_RELATIONSHIP_TYPES'
                    AND language = 'US'
                    AND enabled_flag = 'Y'
                    AND end_date_active IS NULL
                    AND upper(meaning) IN (
                        'CORE CHARGE'
                    )
            )
            AND b.inventory_item_id = inventory_item_id
        UNION
        SELECT
            1
        FROM
            dual
        WHERE
            b.inventory_item_id = 23
    )
GROUP BY
    b.line_id

The methods I tried have all failed to recreate the conditions of the exists clauses.

Why is the t-sql tag used?

@PanagiotisKanavos I was trying to use PL-SQL , might have clicked it by mistake

Can you provide a simpler example or a link to the documentation of the Spark SQL limitation you are trying to work around?

I know these are aimed at SQL Sevrer, but they're still relevant to both Oracle and Spark: Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3) & Bad Habits to Kick : Using old-style JOINs there isn't even a b in apps.oe_order_lines_all, so why would you choose b to alias it as..?

@DavidBrowne-Microsoft the primary issue that Spark SQL does not allow a sub query to access a table that is aliased outside of it while other RDBMSs allow it. How do I rewrite the query such that any inner subquery does not directly refer a table outside.

Spark SQL supports exists and correlated subqueries. Here's  a link to subquery info with examples.

So, once again, can you provide a simpler example or a link to the documentation of the Spark SQL limitation you are trying to work around?

Thanks for your input, this was resolved. The issue was the sub-query within the subquery trying to access the table from the outermost table. Converted that to a CTE and was good to go.
